# Does fabricjs support radial-gradient?

Tags: css, fabricjs

I'm working with Fabric to create Radial-gradient like this

[image]

It can create very easily by css. Like this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#grad1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #1e5799 0%,rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h3>Radial Gradient - Evenly Spaced Color Stops</h3>
<div id="grad1"></div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions do not support gradients.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

But seem fabricJS do not support it. It only support gradient from side to side (?)

Does anyone work with this before. Please give me support.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Yes

Some example: http://jsfiddle.net/fabricjs/58y8b/

```
// initialize fabric canvas and assign to global windows object for debug
var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// Do some initializing stuff
fabric.Object.prototype.set({
    transparentCorners: false,
    cornerColor: 'rgba(102,153,255,0.5)',
    cornerSize: 12,
    padding: 5
});

// Initialze the example
var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: '#ffda4f'
});
var rect2 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 250,
    top: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'rgb(111,154,211)'
});
var rect3 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 400,
    top: 100,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'rgb(166,111,213)'
});
var rect4 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 100,
    top: 400,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: '#ffda4f'
});
var rect5 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 250,
    top: 400,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'rgb(111,154,211)'
});
var rect6 = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 400,
    top: 400,
    width: 100,
    height: 100,
    fill: 'rgb(166,111,213)'
});
canvas.add(rect1, rect2, rect3, rect4, rect5, rect6);

/**
 * setGradient linear gradients example
 */

// horizontal linear gradient
rect1.setGradient('fill', {
    type: 'linear',
    x1: -rect1.width / 2,
    y1: 0,
    x2: rect1.width / 2,
    y2: 0,
    colorStops: {
        0: '#ffe47b',
        1: 'rgb(111,154,211)'
    }
});

// vertical linear gradient
rect2.setGradient('fill', {
    type: 'linear',
    x1: 0,
    y1: -rect2.height / 2,
    x2: 0,
    y2: rect2.height / 2,
    colorStops: {
        0: '#ff4040',
        1: '#e6399b'
    }
});

// diagonal linear gradient
rect3.setGradient('fill', {
    type: 'linear',
    x1: -rect3.width / 2,
    y1: -rect3.height / 2,
    x2: rect3.width / 2,
    y2: rect3.height / 2,
    colorStops: {
        0: 'rgb(166,111,213)',
        0.5: 'rgba(106, 72, 215, 0.5)',
        1: '#200772'
    }
});

/**
 * setGradient radial gradients example
 */

// radial gradient
rect4.setGradient('fill', {
    type: 'radial',
    r1: rect4.width / 2,
    r2: 10,
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: 0,
    y2: 0,
    colorStops: {
        0: '#FF4F4F',
        1: 'rgb(255, 239, 64)'
    }
});

// radial gradient
rect5.setGradient('fill', {
    type: 'radial',
    r1: rect5.width / 2,
    r2: 10,
    x1: 0,
    y1: 0,
    x2: rect4.width / 4,
    y2: rect4.height / 4,
    colorStops: {
        0: '#ffe47b',
        0.5: 'rgb(111,154,211)',
        1: 'rgb(166,111,213)'
    }
});

// radial gradient
rect6.setGradient('fill', {
    type: 'radial',
    r1: 50,
    r2: 80,
    x1: 45,
    y1: 45,
    x2: 52,
    y2: 50,
    colorStops: {
        0: 'rgb(155, 237, 0)',
        1: 'rgba(0, 164, 128,0.4)'
    }
});

canvas.renderAll();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
    let cir = new fabric.Circle({
    left: 100,
    top: 100,
    radius: 30,
    fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
})

cir.setGradient('fill', {
    type: 'radial',
    r1: 30,
    r2: 2,
    x1: 30,
    y1: 30,
    x2: 30,
    y2: 30,
    colorStops: {
        1: 'rgb(113,182,203)',
        0: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
    }
});

fabricCanvas.add(cir);
fabricCanvas.renderAll();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyashar/z6428pta/

Comment: thanks for sharing. do you know if fabric.js can do angles for linear gradients?